# How can I fetch results from elastic search from one column with different values at the same time?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using REST API using PHP for fetching data from Elastic search with following code

```
$params = [
    'index' => $search_index,
    'type' => $search_type,
    'from' => $_POST["from"],
    'size' => $_POST["fetch"],
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'is_validated' => false ] ],
                    [ 'query_string' => [ 'query' => $search_str, 'default_operator' => 'OR' ] ] 
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Now, this is working perfectly and giving me my desired results.

The data that is returned from ES, has one column "result_source" and it has predefined values like CNN, BBC or YouTube etc.

What I need is, I want to filter results on "result_source" column in a way that, I can only fetch the results with the option I want. Like I want results that have "result_source" value only "YouTube" or only "BBC & CNN" or only "CNN or YouTube" etc.

I have already tried "Should" option, but it also returns the data with other values that I don't need. Not sure how to skip those values of "result_source" column in fetching results from ES.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

I am replying to my own question, because I found a solution for it. May be it can help someone else in future.

If anyone is looking for a solution of searching within the field / column of Elastic search, here is what can be done.

```
[ 'query_string' => [ 'query' => $search_str.'(result_source:CNN OR result_source:BBC)', 'default_operator' => 'OR' ] ]
```

"result_source" is actually the field / column name of ES on which filter is applied to return results that have result_source=BBC or result_source=CNN.

This actually solved my issue.